# Conditional scrollbar styles

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, scrollbars

I have the following CSS for my web app to style scrollbars:

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 16px;
  z-index: 100;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 12px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgba(58,193,203, .2);

}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-color: #3AC1CB;
    width: 100px;
}
```

and reset them with a media query when the width is less than a certain size:

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: initial;
    z-index: initial;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    z-index: initial;
    background-color: initial;

  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: initial;
    -webkit-box-shadow: initial;
    background-color: initial;
    width: initial;
  }
```

How can we remove the scrollbar styles using ng-style, when javascript detects for example that it's on an ipad:

I know the basic syntax from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle), but how can this be applied in the case of scrollbars?

Comment: Why would you want both MQs and Javascript to detect the breakpoint for tablet?

Comment: Your question is not really constructive, but since you must know:
small width indicates that it's a touch device, so scrollbars are not needed, MQ are not enough however to determine if it's a touch device, so something with a width of 1024 can be either an ipad or a computer monitor, we want to show scrollbars on computer but not on ipad, hope the logic is clear for ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible solution. Would like to know if there's other possible answers.

```
    var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);

    var iPadStyle = [
        '<style>',
        '::-webkit-scrollbar {',
            'height: initial;',
            'z-index: initial;',
        '}',
        '',
        '::-webkit-scrollbar-track {',
            '-webkit-box-shadow: initial;',
            'border-radius: initial;',
            'z-index: initial;',
            'background-color: initial;',
            '',
        '}',
        '',
        '::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {',
            'border-radius: initial;',
            '-webkit-box-shadow: initial;',
            'background-color: initial;',
            'width: initial;',
         '}',
        '</style>'
    ].join('\n');

    if (isMobile){
        angular.element("head").append(iPadStyle);
    }
```